# Table "play_evolutions" not found

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-evolutions

I have a basic development database configured like this:

```
# Default database configuration using H2 database engine in an in-memory mode
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MYSQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE"
```

I added a script to create the tables from the database in `conf/evolutions/default/1.sql`

When starting the application with `sbt run` and going to any page, Play asks me to apply the script `1.sql`. After pressing the button, I get the following error:

```
JdbcSQLException: Table "play_evolutions" not found; SQL statement: update play_evolutions set last_problem = ? where id = ? [42102-192]`en`
```

Shouldn't the play framework already create this?

### Versions:

```
//project/plugins.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.10")

//build.sbt
lazy val root =
  (project in file("."))
    .enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += jdbc
libraryDependencies += evolutions
```

Comment: Play has always created the `play_evolutions` table for me. Are there any other interesting errors before? It sounds like it's trying to write about a problem into the database (`update play_evolutions set last_problem ...`). Which evolutions settings do you have configured (`play.evolutions.*`)?

Comment: I am also encountering same problem, mine is just a tutorial app so I am using H2 DB and deploying to heroku. It's working fine locally, but not on heroku.

Comment: Alright, I isolated the problem, but wasn't able to debug it... Where is a good place to upload the isolated problem?

Comment: Temporary link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwscnaa69r4w5b3/test-db.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the 1.sql in evolutions.default package, and there might be something that causes the `table not found` thing.

> **USE mydb;**

With this statement, your "working schema" is now **jdbc:h2:mem:play/mydb**.

However the **play_evolutions** table is created just under the root **jdbc:h2:mem:play**, meaning nothing under  **jdbc:h2:mem:play/mydb** called **play_evolutions**, which causes the ERROR.

The solution is easy:

> remove **USE mydb;**

Hope it helps.